# salesforce1: anchor tab on click is not responding only in iOS app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

i am rendering view with few external links inside canvas lightening component.
 when user clicks on that link, expecting it to open in external browser. this is working well in all browsers except in Salesforce mobile app in iOS.

ex code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">click here</a>
```

on click on anchor tag is not responding in ios salesforce mobile app. if i open the same in safari browser, it is opening in new window.

in salesforce help page [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314769&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), i found below paragraph.not sure how to build on top of it.

> For links to external sites, within Salesforce for iOS App, Salesforce
>   will open a child browser window. This is technically not the Safari
>   application just yet. From this window, you have the option to launch
>   in Safari, which will then leave the Salesforce mobile app and load
>   you page accordingly.

can someone suggest if there are any limitations from salesforce? if so what is the way out?

Comment: Assuning you are talking about sf mobile app or an app created using publisher, the new windows do not open properly on iOS platforms. You need to redirect in current window and handle the back and forward buttons.

Comment: i cannot do it as the url i want to open will not open inside iframe. how can i overcome that restriction.